# Getting error while using the javascript Sdk for amazon s3 to Create bucket to my live repository

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Getting error while using the javascript Sdk for amazon s3 to Create bucket to amazon
This is the code that I am using in my javascript file

```
[$scope.creds = {
            bucket: $rootScope.SIGNATURE_CREDS.bucket,
            access_key: $rootScope.SIGNATURE_CREDS.access_key,
            secret_key: $rootScope.SIGNATURE_CREDS.secret_key
      }
      AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: $scope.creds.access_key, secretAccessKey: $scope.creds.secret_key });
      AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
            var params = {
            Bucket:'AliNafees',
            ACL: 'public-read '
            };
      var s3 = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: $scope.creds.bucket, ACL: "public-read" } });
      s3.createBucket(params, function(err, data) {
      console.log(err, data);
      });][1]
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: https://s3.amazonaws.com/AliNafeess 403 (Forbidden)
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3.amazonaws.com/AliNafeess. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested

Answer (score 0):

When you create a bucket, it has the CORS attribute. Usually it is set by clicking it and then simply clicking save. Try to set this value in your code, usually the default value of it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: Hi
I am doing that from that Client Side using AWS
So I have no xml like so you shown above
So How I can do that?